# Get ListViewItem from a LinkButton when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ASPX page like so

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lvLB" OnClick="lvLB_OnClick" runat="server">ButtonLabel</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then the ASPX.cs file:

```
protected void lvLB_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    ListViewDataItem data = (ListViewDataItem)lb.Parent;
    DataRowView rV = data.DataItem as DataRowView;
}
```

The list view is correctly databound with a DataSet object and does show correct data on the page.

I'm trying to get the DataRowView of the Item that the button was clicked it, yet the above will return null at data.DataItem as DataRowView.

What have I missed?

Comment: What is the data source for ListView?

Comment: You should use itemCommand event of ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `DataItem` to `DataRowView` only if the underlying type is `DataView` or `DataTable` . otherwise it's not convertible right-away. Your component is a `ListView`, so you have to map it yourself if you need `DataRowView`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to get row data through `Select` command button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Accessing BoundField Column
    string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

    //Accessing TemplateField Column controls
    string country = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;

    lblValues.Text = "<b>Name:</b> " + name + " <b>Country:</b> " + country;
}
```

Here is the complete example and demo:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx